# Does db.query() crash the app if there is no values in the database?

Tags: java, android, sql, database

Running this query to get data from internal Android database and assign to cursor:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, 
                       new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_SURNAME },
                       KEY_ID + "=?",  
                       new String[] { String.valueOf(name) }, null, null, null);

if (cursor != null)
    cursor.moveToFirst();

Record rec = new Record(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
```

App crashes on executing this code.

Exception : `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0`.

Could this be due to the fact that there is no value in KEY_ID as I haven't added any rows before I run this method?

Comment: any log, stacktrace, anything ? more code, may be?

Comment: No, a query with no results is something usual.

Comment: CursorIndexOutOfBoundsExtension: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `query()` should not kill the app. But if something went wrong there it'd throw exception which you most likely not trying to catch and this kills your app. I'd anyway check a) logcat output for the crash stack trace or following lines - it's possible you just **assume** there's always data returned and try to access it there leading to crash.

You should always check if your query returned anything, like:

```
Cursor cursor = mDb.query(....);
if( cursor.getCount() > 0 ) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    .....
}
```

or simply

```
Cursor cursor = mDb.query(....);
if( cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
    .....
}
```

as you can easily get valid, non `null` cursor which holds no data (zero rows returned). Attempt to access non existing data from such cursor will lead to exception being thrown (and crash if exception is not caught).

**Edit**

try catching the exception and then see the logcat for the culprit:

```
try {
    Cursor cursor = mDb.query(....);
    if( cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
        .....
    }
} catch ( Exception e ) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: CursorIndexOutOfBoundsExtension: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0.

Comment: As I said. See edited answer for a hint. BTW: this was "Exception" not "Extension" :)

Comment: I see your point. Thank you. But It still fails on db.query() line. I recon because the table is empty (it is the fact that it is empty). Could this be the reason that lead to crash?

Comment: no. Empty table is perfectly fine and it's normal state of the table. You can crash on query if you try to select columns that do not exist in the table. See edit again

Comment: Seems like the cursor is empty if table is empty. And I haven't checked the cursor.getCount() properly. Fixed that and it looks that the issue had been resolved! Thank you. :)

Comment: Cursor is empty because there's no data it could point to, so this is fine. That's why it's important to check if your query returned any data. Welcome :)

Comment: Actually, there isn't any need to check cursor.getCount().  cursor.moveToFirst() returns false if there is no first item.

Comment: in fact it doesn't matter how you check as long as you do the check. the point is you can have valid cursor and no data